# Wrap pdf vertically in swift

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I have few pdf files where the person who reads has to zoom in and pan around to move to next paragraph.

Is there anyway i can view pdf in PDFKit or Webkit by just wrapping the texts in pdf and disable horizontal scroll.

I have already tried PDFKit and viewing inside a webview.

[image]

Comment: please could you paste some image examples of what you have now and what is your desirable experience

Comment: okay.. i have added an image above ( edited the question)

Comment: Do you have control of how the pdf's content is generated or your app simply displays pdfs ? It's not fully clear to me as what you have now seems to be like a 2 column layout and it seems you want to make it a 1 column layout. If you are the one generating the PDF - some steps can be taken to get close to your desired result. Would be nice to see your PDF generation code if this is your case.

Comment: i am not the one who generates pdf...i need to show some random pdf from web...thats all...as you said...it should be one 1 column

Comment: In that case, it is not so straight forward but possible with PDFKit. What comes to my mind is first you need to read the contents of the PDF and do some processing to figure out the different paragraphs. Here is an introduction to that: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-using-pdfkit . Then you need to build a PDF based on your constraints and requirements - here is how you go about doing that: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit